# Change reactive time for dygraph's dyRangeSelector in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I'm building a Shiny application where I want to use the `dyRangeSelector` from `dygraphs` to provide the input period.

My problem is that I only want the reactive change to fire when the selector receives a "MouseUp"-event, ie., when the user is *done* with choosing the period. Right now events are dispatched as the selector is moved which results in a lagged app since the computations done for each period take a few seconds. Essentially, Shiny is *too* reactive for my taste here (I know this it the wrong way round - normally we want the apps to be super reactive).

Can I modify when the reactive request is dispatched?

Here's a small example that shows the problem.

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(magrittr)

# Create simple user interface
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
            dygraphOutput("dygraph")
            ),    
    mainPanel(
            plotOutput("complicatedPlot")
            )
    )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    ## Read the data once.                                                                                       
    dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols("NASDAQ:GOOG", src = "google",
                   from = "2017-01-01",
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
    })

    ## Extract the from and to from the selector    
    values <- reactiveValues()    

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$dygraph_date_window)) {
            rangewindow <- strftime(input$dygraph_date_window[[1]], "%Y-%m-%d")
            from <- rangewindow[1]
            to <- rangewindow[2]
        } else {
            from <- "2017-02-01"
            to <- Sys.Date()+1
        }
        values[["from"]] <- from
        values[["to"]] <- to
    })

    ## Render the range selector    
    output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
        dygraph(dataInput()[,4]) %>% dyRangeSelector() %>% dyOptions(retainDateWindow = TRUE)
    })

    ## Render the "complicated" plot
    output$complicatedPlot <- renderPlot({
        plot(1,1)
        text(1,1, values[["from"]])
        Sys.sleep(1) ## Inserted to represent computing time
    })
})

## run app                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function in shiny called `debounce` which might pretty much suit your needs. If you rewrite the limits to a reactive expression (as opposed to observe), you can wrap it into `debounce` with a specification of time in milliseconds to wait before evaluation. Here is an example with 1000ms:

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(magrittr)

# Create simple user interface
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dygraphOutput("dygraph")
    ),    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("complicatedPlot")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ## Read the data once.                                                                                       
  dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols("NASDAQ:GOOG", src = "google",
               from = "2017-01-01",
               auto.assign = FALSE)
  })

  ## Extract the from and to from the selector    
  values <- reactiveValues()    

  limits <- debounce(reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$dygraph_date_window)) {
      rangewindow <- strftime(input$dygraph_date_window[[1]], "%Y-%m-%d")
      from <- rangewindow[1]
      to <- rangewindow[2]
    } else {
      from <- "2017-02-01"
      to <- Sys.Date()+1
    }
    list(from = from,
         to = to)
  }), 1000)

  ## Render the range selector    
  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(dataInput()[,4]) %>% dyRangeSelector() %>% dyOptions(retainDateWindow = TRUE)
  })

  ## Render the "complicated" plot
  output$complicatedPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1,1)
    text(1,1, limits()[["from"]])
    Sys.sleep(1) ## Inserted to represent computing time
  })
})

## run app                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

This basically means that the reactive expression must be returning the same value for at least 1s to be send to its dependencies. You can experiment with the best time.

Comment: Wonderful. That was exactly what I was after. It "costs" me the waiting time at startup, but that's entirely fine. Cheers!